# Best way to get necessary external data for an R package

Tags: r, cran

I have an [R package](https://github.com/ropensci/gender) which predicts genders from first names. To do so it requires several largish data sets. I've put these into a [separate R package](https://github.com/lmullen/gender-data-pkg). Ideally the `gender` package could depend on the `genderdata` package and both would be accepted by CRAN. However it looks like CRAN won't take the `genderdata` package because it is too big (26MB). (I guess "big data" >= 5MB.)

So my question is this: what is the best way to get that data into my `gender` package if I can't include the `genderdata` package in `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

My thought is to depend on `devtools` and provide a function like this:

```
install_gender_data <- function() {
  if(!require(genderdata)) devtools::install_github("lmullen/gender-data-pkg")
}
```

Then I would use `.onLoad()` and a package startup message to tell users to run that function if they don't already have `genderdata` loaded.

Comment: Sounds good. Any way you can include a mini-version of the dataset so your package can run some tests without needing the big data?

Comment: That's a clever idea. I was wondering how to make the tests pass on CRAN/Travis without access to the data package.

Comment: Possibly subjective point of view, but CRAN packages should be general in nature.  If your package only predicts names based on a biased set of one country, that's not very general.  Suggestion: include only a sample of data, and then make it very clear what the data format should be for your functions to work.  Then your users can create their own data sets.  Additionally, make it easy to download your data, e.g. by using [these ideas](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/sourcegithubdata-simple-function-for.html)

Comment: Point taken. But I'd say that a package should solve a particular problem well. In sciences that might mean abstraction and generalization; in history it means relying on particulars. And when I get a chance I'm going to add European data.

Comment: @Andrie _CRAN packages should be general_ Who says that?

Comment: I think your solution is good. And your tests do have access to the data,  at least on Travis you can just install the data package. I don't know what CRAN maintainers think of this, though.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I said that, hence my statement it's a subjective point of view.  This is probably a topic for a different forum, a blog post or R-devel, perhaps.

Comment: BTW: Why you want `genderdata` in `Imports` part? Shouldn't it be in `Suggests` section as needed for examples, vignettes, etc? Is this dataset necessary for modelling on user data?

Comment: The function won't work without the data. Yes, it should be in `Suggests` if it can't be loaded from CRAN.